# 2D array of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, arrayofstring

I'm working an application which required the below thinngs.

```
const char List1[2][10] = {"Stack","Overflow"};
const char List2[2][10] = {"Goo","Gle"};
const char List3[2][10] = {"Face","Book"};
const char List4[2][10] = {"Pizza","Hutt"};
```

Now I've to store List1,..,List4 into another array as explained below.

```
char **var_name[2][2] = { &List1, &List2, &List3, &List4};
```

What I should called to "var_name"? & Is it right way?

Also If I want to print "Book" using XYZ, then how I can print it?

Answer (score 1):

`List1` is an array of two arrays of 10 `const char`. So `&List1` is a pointer to an array of two arrays of 10 `char`. If `var_name` is an array of those, it is an array of pointers to an array of two arrays of 10 `const char`. You can build a declaration for that piece by piece:

- `var_name` is an array…: `var_name[]`.
- … of pointers: `*var_name[]`.
- …to an array of two…: `(*var_name[])[2]`.
- …arrays of 10…: `(*var_name[])[2][10]`.
- … `const char`: `const char (*var_name[])[2][10]`.

Then you can define and initialize it:

```
char (*var_name[])[2][10] = { &List1, &List2, &List3, &List4};
```

`"Book"` is in element 1 of `List3`, which is in element 2 of `var_name`, so you can refer to it with `(*var_name[2])[1]`.

Note that this requires the `*`, because `var_name[i]` is a pointer. This follows the sample code you gave where the array is initialized with `&List1`. It is more common to use a pointer to the first element of an array instead of a pointer to the array. (The addresses in memory are the same, but the types are different.)

Suppopse we want to eliminate this unnecessary pointer level and initialize `var_name` with `{ List1, List2, List3, List4 }`. As usual in C, those arrays will be automatically converted to pointers to their first elements. The first element of each of those arrays is an array of 10 `const char`. So we will be initializing `var_name` with pointers to arrays of 10 `const char`.

Thus, `var_name` will be an array of pointers to arrays of 10 `const char`. Again, we can build the declaration piece by piece:

- `var_name` is an array…: `var_name[]`.
- … of pointers…: `*var_name[]`.
- … to arrays of 10…: `(*var_name[])[10]`.
- … `const char`…: `const char (*var_name[])[10]`.

Then the definition and initialization is:

```
const char (*var_name[])[10] = { List1, List2, List3, List4 };
```

Now the elements of `List3` are pointed to by `var_name[2]`, so we can refer to `"Book"` with `var_name[2][1]`.